# Invalid Allocation Size - Object Variables

Tags: c++, class

I am in my first C++ this semester and am having some issues with a `MyVector` class I created earlier on in the class. I made variables global for the object which is a "NO NO" as my teacher said for object oriented programming. I believed I have declared the variables correctly now, but ever since I am receiving an

> "Invalid allocation size: 4294967295 bytes." When calling my push_back
>   function.

Below is my code  (MyVector.h, and MyVector.cpp), I understand that using `using namespace std;` is not best practice but this is how my teacher wants it.... I don't know why.

I have stepped through my code and can't identify what I need to do next. I have a feeling it is how I had the variable declared before. They were previously in the MyVector.cpp declared globally as follows before the change.

```
//Declarations
int vSize;
int* myArray;
int startCap = 2;
const int TWO = 2;
const int ZERO = 0;
```

Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

The Call from the driver.cpp

```
cout << "\nCreating a vector Sam of size 4.";
MyVector sam( 4 );

cout << "\nPush 12 values into the vector.";
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    sam.push_back(i);
```

MyVector.h

```
class MyVector
{

public:

    int vSize;
    int* myArray;
    int startCap;

    //Constructor
    MyVector ();
    MyVector (int n);

    //Deconstructor
    ~MyVector ();

    //Copy Constructor
    MyVector(const MyVector&);

    //Overloaded Assignment Operator
    MyVector& operator=(const MyVector&);

    //Getter Function: size
    //Purpose: Return the size of the vector
    //Return Type: int
    //Parameters: NONE
    int size () const;

    //Getter Funcation: capacity
    //Purpose: Return the capacity of the vector
    //Return Type: int
    //Parameters: NONE
    int capacity () const;

    //Setter Funcation: clear
    //Purpose: Clears the contents of the vector and sets the siz to zero and the capacity to two 
    //Return Type: void
    //Parameters: NONE
    void clear ();

    //Setter Funcation: push_back
    //Purpose: Adds integer to vector. If vector is not big enough double the vectors current capacity
    //Return Type: void
    //Parameters: int n
    void push_back (int n);

    //Getter Function: at
    //Purpose: Return value of emement at position n
    //Return Type: Int
    //Parameters: int n
    int at (int n) const;

    // overloaded << operator - a nonmember
    // make it a friend so it can see the array
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const MyVector& s);
};
```

MyVector.cpp

```
//default constructors
MyVector::MyVector()
{
    int startCap = 2;
    int vSize = 0;
    myArray = new int[startCap];
}

MyVector::MyVector(int n)
{
    int startCap = n;
    int vSize = 0;
    myArray = new int[startCap];
}

//Deconstructor
MyVector::~MyVector()
{
    //deleting myArray and clearing it
    if (myArray != NULL)
    {
        delete [] myArray;
        myArray = NULL;
    }
}

// Copy constructor
// Purpose: Copy the data into this Array
// Parameters: a MyVector object
// Returns: none
MyVector::MyVector( const MyVector& v)
{
// Be sure that the string is not null
if ( v.myArray != NULL )
{
    // allocate storage and copy char array
    startCap = v.startCap;     
    //theStr = new char[strlen(b.theStr) + 1];
    myArray = new int[startCap];
    //strncpy(theStr, b.theStr, theStrLen );
    for (int i = 0; i < startCap; i++)
        myArray[i] = v.myArray[i];
}
else  // nothing to copy
{
    myArray = NULL;
    startCap = 0;
}
}

// The overloaded assignment operator
MyVector& MyVector::operator= (const MyVector& v)
{
// test for self-copy
if (this == &v)
   return *this;

// Consider two cases.
if (startCap >= v.startCap)  // there is room
{
    if (v.myArray != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < startCap; i++)
        {
            this->myArray[i] = v.myArray[i];
        }
    }
    else // copying a null string
       myArray = NULL;

    startCap = v.startCap;
    return *this;
}
else  // not enough room
{
    // delete the original array
    delete [] myArray;

    startCap = v.startCap;
    if (startCap > 0) // okay, something to copy
    {
       // allocate the storage and copy
        myArray = new int[startCap + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < vSize; i++)
        {
            this->myArray[i] = v.myArray[i];
        }
    }
   else // nothing to copy
      myArray = NULL;

   return *this;
   }
}

//Getter Function: size
//Purpose: Return the size of the vector
//Return Type: int
//Parameters: NONE
int MyVector::size() const
{
    return vSize;
}

//Getter Funcation: capacity
//Purpose: Return the capacity of the vector
//Return Type: int
//Parameters: NONE
int MyVector::capacity() const
{
    return startCap;
}

//Setter Funcation: clear
//Purpose: Clears the contents of the vector and sets the siz to zero and the capacity to two 
//Return Type: void
//Parameters: NONE
void MyVector::clear() 
{
    //clearing the array and setting the array to the default cap of 2 and size of 0
    if (myArray != NULL)
    {
        delete [] myArray;
        myArray = NULL;
    }

    vSize = 0;
    startCap = 2;
    int* myArray = new int[startCap];
}

//Setter Funcation: push_back
//Purpose: Adds integer to vector. If vector is not big enough double the vectors     current capacity
//Return Type: void
//Parameters: int n
void MyVector::push_back(int n)
{


//verifying the we are not writting the value
//past the capacity of the array
if(vSize + 1 > startCap)
{
    //Doubling the array size
    startCap = vSize * 2;
    //creating a temp array
    int* temp = new int[startCap];

    //for loop copying the contents of myArray to temp
    for (int i = 0; i < vSize; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = myArray [i];
    }

    //deleting the myArray
    delete[] myArray;
    //copying myArray from temp
    myArray = temp;
}

//finding the end of the array and incrementing and adding one to the array
myArray[vSize] = n;
vSize++;
}

//Getter Function: at
//Purpose: Return value of emement at position n
//Return Type: Int
//Parameters: int n
int MyVector::at(int n) const
{
    //If statment that returns value of the point in the array
    //or throws an error telling the user the index at which it failed
    if(n < vSize)
        return myArray[n];
    throw n;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const MyVector& s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.vSize; i++)
        out << s.myArray[i] << ' ';
    return out;
}
```

Comment: "Invalid allocation size" means you should check anything wrong with usage of `new`, so start from there. Plus, `const int TWO = 2;`
`const int ZERO = 0;` is a bad practice, use something meaningful to name your variable.

Answer (score 2):

you are creating a same variable within the constructor and clear, which has the same name is the one in the class, initialize it. 
and by the time you leave the constructor or clear, the main variables, don't get any changes.

its an initializing issue, especially the ones in the constructor

in clear function

```
int* myArray = new int[startCap];
```

should be

```
myArray = new int[startCap];
```

also inside the constructor

```
  int startCap = n;
  int vSize = 0;
```

should be

```
  startCap = n;
  vSize = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to assign to an instance variable, don't put the type on the name. That'll create a local variable with the same name as the instance variable instead of assigning to the actual instance variable, causing your instance variables to have incorrect, possibly even uninitialized values. This problem shows up in your first two constructors and your `clear` method.